# Is JQuery in chrome extension a security concern?

Tags: chrome, browser-extensions, jquery

This is the relevant part of my manifest.json file:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "content.js""]
    }
  ]
```

I noticed that now I have jquery on every page I go to and I was wondering if it's a security concern.
I don't do anything fishy but I wonder whether some sites could try to exploit having jquery in scope.

My extension is supposed to work on every page so I can't blacklist certain sites.

I downloaded jquery from the official CDN once and it's now in my extension.

Comment: there is a "sandbox" in each browser which should prevent any page from accessing your extension's scripts.  also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you don't have to worry about it.**

Having jQuery in your extension doesn't pose any security risk. Javascript is used to run the code on the client-side of the browser if any malicious website wants to run JS on a system, they can embed it within their evil website itself;  They don't have to rely on an extension to provide jQuery to do malicious things.

As [@pcalkins](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/225041/pcalkins) pointed out in the comment, the browser is sandboxed and even extensions cannot execute anything outside of that.